# Photoelectric effect and the type of the incident light

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Given the relation between the voltage **V** and the photocurrent **I** .
[image]

Does this graph hold for both monochromatic light and white light? And why there is a value for the photocurrent **I** at **V**=0 ?

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html

Comment: For a good explanation of the way to voltage on the anode is applied look at this answer here https://www.quora.com/What-is-stopping-potential-in-photoelectric-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because the stopping potential $V_{\rm stopping}$ depends on the frequency of the incident light $f$ as follows

$$eV_{\rm stopping}=hf-\phi$$

where $\phi$ is the work function energy of the material on which the light is incident.  Thus white light which consists of a range of frequencies has a range of stopping potentials.

Comment: Okay, what if we made the comparison at V=0 ? Will it still hold?

Comment: I would doubt that the current would be the same for different frequencies of light. Note that some parts of the white light spectrum would not emit any photoelectrons. You can investigate this with the [PhET Photoelectric Emission](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/photoelectric) simulation.